# Problems upgrading from 14.04 to 16.04 January 2020

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade from 14.04 to 16,04
I am using this steps suggested by https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g6GUGoX5u8M&t=197s ,  however I am stuck after the first step and this is what it shows on my screen:

```
Reading package lists... Done
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://repo.vivaldi.com stable Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 9658E8044A3AA3D6
W: Failed to fetch http://repo.vivaldi.com/archive/deb/dists/stable/Release  
W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/patrick-dessalle/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: xx.xxx.xx.xx xx]
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/patrick-dessalle/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: xx. xxx. xx.xx.xx]

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
```

I can not continue with step 2.

I would appreciate your help.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, during upgrading LTS to the newer release, the PPA and non-official Ubuntu packages are not going to upgrade themselves. You can do it later, if the package is still valid in the newer release. Simply type 'sudo do-release-upgrade' then you get it.

Comment: I looked at one of those PPA's, it didn't support 14.04 either (support ended at 11.10) - http://ppa.launchpad.net/patrick-dessalle/ppa/ubuntu/dists/   Disable or delete those PPA's you weren't able to use since 2012 (well before 2014-April or 14.04).  I would also stick with official guides, or on sites like this (eg. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades).   I'd also consider a re-install given the lack of maintenance the system appears to have had.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are working with an **unsupported version of Ubuntu**, version 14.04. "Unsupported" also means **no upgrade is supported** anymore. So quit your attempts to upgrade this way immediately.

As a general advise, do not upgrade over an older version. Instead make sure that the backup of your private user files is up to date, and then perform a fresh install of the latest long term release edition of Ubuntu 18.04.

A fresh install is the best, most tested and most trouble free approach for any operating system. Doing so, you are adopting the thoroughly tested system defaults. In contrast, when you upgrade, you are carrying over old configuration which may not be optimal, may conflict with newer configuration settings, or cause more severe issues altogether.

A fresh install takes no more than 15 - 20 minutes. It is the least likely to run into problems. You then have a stable, fresh and tested system where you can put your own data back.

Answer (score 0):

You are likely to encounter quite a few errors thanks to the fact that you are using 14.04, a old release, and EOL, so it doesn't support any upgrades.  Backing up your data and making a clean, fresh installation of the release of your choice (I recommend 20.04 Focal Fossa) would be the right thing to do.